# Moving a 2D numpy subarray efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array that represents a greyscale image, such as

```
image = numpy.array([
    [.0, .0, .0, .0, .1, .3, .5, .0],
    [.0, .0, .0, .0, .4, .4, .6, .0],
    [.0, .0, .0, .0, .3, .3, .7, .0],
    [.0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0],
    [.0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0],
    [.0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0],
])
```

I would like to move a sub-array to a new location, filling the values left behind with some constant (say 0.0). For example, moving the 3x3 sub-array from center position of (1, 5) to center position (3, 3) would result in:

```
numpy.array([
    [.0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0],
    [.0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0],
    [.0, .0, .1, .3, .5, .0, .0, .0],
    [.0, .0, .4, .4, .6, .0, .0, .0],
    [.0, .0, .3, .3, .7, .0, .0, .0],
    [.0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0],
])
```

Is there an efficient way to perform such a move?

Comment: Can you post your current code for moving the subarray, along with some benchmarks showing why it is inefficient?

Comment: Can there be any other non-zero values that you want to preserve (without moving)?  If not, then the 'copy to a blank array' in the answers is the best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the starting index of where you want to move from and move to, we can use **`np.zeros_like`** and numpy indexing:

```
h = w = 3
sub = image[0:0+w,4:4+h]
out = np.zeros_like(image)
```

Then assign:

```
out[2:2+w, 2:2+h] = sub
```

Output:

```
array([[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using a custom function. The concept of "centre" is only well-defined as integer coordinates for an odd length, e.g. (3 x 3); I have also limited my answer to square blocks.

```
def mover(A, c_in, c_out, size):
    side = int((size - 1) / 2)
    arr = A[c_in[0]-side: c_in[0]+side+1, c_in[1]-side: c_in[1]+side+1]
    res = np.zeros(shape=A.shape)
    res[c_out[0]-side: c_out[0]+side+1, c_out[1]-side: c_out[1]+side+1] = arr
    return res

centre_in = (1, 5)
centre_out = (3, 3)
size = 3

res = mover(image, centre_in, centre_out, size)

array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.1,  0.3,  0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.4,  0.4,  0.6,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.3,  0.3,  0.7,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```